# Is there a way to get the duration time for a running cronjob?

Tags: cron, duration

I want to monitor the long running time cronjob.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEk10.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].  Using images in questions is frowned upon for anything that can be described in text.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting job blablabla" >>/tmp/job.log
date >>/tmp/duration.log

# THE REST OF THE CODE FOR SCRIPT blablabla

echo "End of job blablabla" >>/tmp/duration.log
date >>/tmp/duration.log
```

Every execution of the script will add entries with start and end time

---

Or directly in the cron:

```
* * * * * time -o /tmp/timing.txt blablabla.sh >/tmp/blablabla.out 2>/tmp/blablabla.out2
```

- `time -o` shows the resource usage duration for the command.
- The `-o` option specifies which file to send the results into.
- The `>` and `2>` redirections are to keep logs of the output and errors.  But that is not related to `time` itself, just a good idea all around with cron jobs.